# How can I change textbox contents based on which control the mouse is hovering over in WPF?

Tags: wpf

I have a textbox and several custom controls. Each of the custom controls has a "hint text" property that should appear in the textbox when that control is hovered over.

In winforms I was able to just give the custom control a textbox property and change its text property with events, however in WPF it instead makes a new textbox when I give it a property.

So how can I get the desired functionality?

Comment: look into styles and triggers. I am almost 100% sure you can do this purely in XAML. Also, What have you tried? Where is your example code? Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please post questions that can be solved. Not theory

Comment: Put a property of type `string` in the data context of all the controls involved. Set that property in a trigger on property `MouseOver` to the hint text.

Comment: @AnthonyRussell I'm not sure if I'm allowed to get meta in the comments, but in the interest of asking better questions in the future, I'd like some clarification. What example code would be helpful in this context? I've asked how to do something, is this considered not solvable because there's multiple solutions?

Comment: @Sand You say "in WPF it instead makes a new textbox when I give it a property". Why not post the code - you have already tried something and it's useful for us to see, even if you think it's the wrong approach.

Comment: @Sand Think of Stack Overflow more as a peer review site than a Q & A site. Professionals use this site in order to solve difficult problems. We post what we have tried and what relevant code there is. Then our peers across the community are able to suggest better ways to do things or point out bugs in the code.

Comment: @Sand I would suggest reviewing this http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score -1):

Assuming your custom controls all inherit from a common base type (which I have called CustomControl as an example)...

XAML:

```
<TextBox x:Name=TextBox/>

<Button VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Click="ButtonBase_OnClick" MouseEnter="UIElement_OnMouseEnter" MouseLeave="UIElement_OnMouseLeave">test</Button>
```

Code behind:

```
private void UIElement_OnMouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox.Text = ((CustomControl) sender).HintText;
}

private void UIElement_OnMouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox.Text = string.Empty;
}
```